# Backup azure analysis service on a storage with firewall rules

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage, azure-analysis-services, azure-nsg

is it possible to make a backup of an azure analysis service on a storage account which ist protected via firewall rules? I have set the exception “allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account”. But If I try to set the backup on the azure analysis service side I get this error message:

*Invalid backup blob container xxxxx: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it via **only** setting the exception "allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account” since azure analysis service is not included in the [trusted Microsoft services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services).

If you have selected `allow access from selected network` in the firewall and virtual networks of the storage account, actually you have enabled the firewall of the storage account, so you have a forbidden error.

Comment: Do you have any Idea, whatever this setting in storage account (allow access from selected network). How can I backup my cube?

Comment: What you want is like [VNet integration for Azure Storage and Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/announcing-virtual-network-integration-for-azure-storage-and-azure-sql/). But it does not work for analysis service because currently [VNet service endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) do not support for azure analysis service, also there is a similar feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/556165-azure-analysis-services/suggestions/38125696-enable-analysis-service-to-access-same-region-vnet).

Comment: or you can try to add the client IP for an azure analysis service to the IP range in the firewall of Azure storage account But I do not aware of how to get the IP list.

Comment: You could add the total IP range of azure analysis services PaaS. Since this is the range of the whole azure region, probably best to only allow it for data load and then take it out again e.g. via automation runbook. Still not ideal though.